# Моя Винда сошла с ума: байты свободного пространства улетают в никуда со скоростью 2-5 мб в секунду

Tags: windows, windows-7

Доброго всем здравия.
Тут как-то удалял 32bit\устанавливал 64bit серьезное ПО (естественно) лицензионное ;).Ведь ставит зачем-то параллельно 2 версии и 32 и 64! ПО-то не маленькое! То Мах, то редактор ПэЗэДэ файлов.
И тут такое!!! О_о?!
Одним словом байты свободного пространства улетают в никуда со скоростью 2-5 мб в секунду!!И так до АБСОЛЮТНОГО нуля байт на диске C!
Посмотрел размеры всех каталогов - вроде не изменяются.
Перенёс уже гигов 10, освобождая пространство, НО!
Но эта штука не заканчивается! О только что освободишь, тут же опять через 10-30 секунд 0 байт на С!
Единственный каталог, к которому не подступился это 'WindowsImageBackup' и 'DrWeb Quarantine'
В ХР мог, тут 7-ка, не умею...
Что это может быть?
Про всякие кэши, темпы, функции restore я в курсе.
Что это такое может быть?

Comment: Оказалось рос (до 17 ГБ!!!!)  какой-то файл от 3ДэМаха!  А главное, Винда и Коммандер(что именно удивительно)  Не могли определить эту "грыжу"!

Comment: @IrandaЗашибись, 12 лет в ИТ(системное администрирование) + вопрос по администрированию, и в раздел юзеров? Идите сами туда!

Comment: I_CaR:[Offtop] Iranda - это вообще-то модер тут. Да и членами тут меряться ни к чему! Замечу лишь, что у меня стаж уже 27 лет, и я так не выёживаюсь, чего и тебе советую! Здесь - сеть знаний, а не дешёвого выпендрёжа![\Offtop]

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще-то большинство серьёзных программ имеют функционал настройки, где можно указывать пути в файлам резервных копий, временным рабочим файлам и т.п. Надо бы пользовать эти функции, вы скорее всего всё оставляете по умолчанию.

Comment: Согласен. Было у меня такое в стародавние времена под 95-ой с фотошопом 5.5

Comment: Тоже соглашусь, так как ПО очень много разностороннего.

Answer (score 0):

Глянь на размер файла подкачки. Если он при работе 3DMAX превышает 150-200% оперативы, то значит - оперативы маловато!

Answer (score 0):

Коллега, снеси винду, вообще форматируй жёсткий диск и поставь другую. Это какая то ошибка в сборке операционки.

Comment: кстати проверь какая у тебя оптимальная операционная система должна стоять, на 32-бита или на 64-бита

Comment: Читайте внимательнее, ответ уже был дан, т.е. не ответ, а причина была найдена."какая у тебя оптимальная операционная система должна стоять"Это как понимать?  Т.е. посмотрел на пк, если 086-ой, то 16-бит, 286-ой = 24 бита, 386 = 32-бита, современные, начиная от "Athlon 64" и 64 бита?  Так что ли по вашему?:)